# WPF Type Select list box Query

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am learning WPF and MVVM, and have written a simple Type-Select List box in WPF as a learning practice program.
Though it works,I have three questions which are as under:-

1)How to set the Text property of TxtMail via DataBinding?Currently it messes up with other logic if i set Text property in XAML via DataBinding.I do not want to set the text property of Txtmail directly from Code-Behind,while setting the same via DataBinding in XAML messes up things owing to my limited understanding of the subject.

2)The ItemSource of ListBox named AllMatching is being set from Code-Behind since it is changing programatically with text search patterns.How can i set it from XAML?

3)Is there a way i can remove the logic of GUI Control Events and include the same in XAML?
The entire code is as under:-

ViewModel:

```
 public class VM_Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int p_ID;
    public double p_SP, p_CP;
    public string p_Name;
    public List<DM_Data> AllData;
    public List<DM_Data> DynamicData;
    public Visibility p_ListVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    private DM_Data _currentRec;
    public DM_Data CurrentRec
    {
        get { return _currentRec; }
        set { _currentRec = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CurrentRec"); }
    }

    public VM_Data()
    {
        LoadData();
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return p_ID; }
        set
        {
            if (p_ID != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
                p_ID = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public double SP
    {

        get { return p_SP; }
        set
        {
            if (p_SP != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SP");
                p_SP = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public double CP
    {
        get { return p_CP; }
        set
        {
            if (p_CP != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CP");
                p_CP = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Visibility ListVisibility
    {
        get { return p_ListVisibility; }
        set
        {
            p_ListVisibility = p_ListVisibility != value ? value : p_ListVisibility;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ListVisibility");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return p_Name; }
        set
        {
            if (p_Name != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
                p_Name = value;
            }
        }
    }


    private void LoadData()
    {
        AllData = new List<DM_Data>();
        DynamicData = new List<DM_Data>();
        string[] strNames = "Jatinder;Shashvat;shashikala;shamsher;shahid;justin;jatin;jolly;ajay;ahan;vijay;suresh;namita;nisha;negar;zenith;zan;zen;zutshi;harish;hercules;harman;ramesh;shashank;mandeep;aman;amandeep;amarjit;asim;akshay;amol;ritesh;ritivik;riz;samana;samaira;bhagwandass;bhagwan;bhawna;bhavna".Split(';');
        for(int i=0;i<=strNames.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
        {
            DM_Data NewRec = new DM_Data();
            NewRec.CP = new Random().Next(200, 400);
            NewRec.SP = new Random().Next(1, 10);
            NewRec.ID = i + 1;
            NewRec.Name = strNames[i];
            AllData.Add(NewRec);
        }
        AllData = DynamicData = AllData.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList();

    }
    private void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
        }
    }
}
```

DataModel:

```
public class DM_Data
    {
        public int p_ID;
        public double p_SP, p_CP;
        public string p_Name;
        public Visibility p_ListVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return p_ID; }
            set { p_ID = value; }
        }

        public Visibility ListVisibility
        {
            get { return p_ListVisibility; }
            set { p_ListVisibility = value; }
        }
        public double SP
        {
            get { return p_SP; }
            set { p_SP = value; }
        }
        public double CP
        {
            get { return p_CP; }
            set { p_CP = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return p_Name; }
            set { p_Name = value; }
        }

}
```

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TypeSelect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TypeSelect"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Canvas>
            <TextBox x:Name="TxtMail" Width="244" FontSize="14" Canvas.Left="36" Canvas.Top="34" Height="25" GotFocus="TxtMail_GotFocus" LostFocus="TxtMail_LostFocus"   KeyUp="TxtMail_KeyUp" MouseUp="TxtMail_MouseUp"   />
            <ListBox x:Name="AllMatching" Width="{Binding ElementName=TxtMail,Path=Width}" MinHeight="10" MaxHeight="100" Canvas.Top="54" Canvas.Left="36"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRec,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" Visibility="{Binding ListVisibility,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" KeyUp="AllMatching_KeyUp" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MouseUp="AllMatching_MouseUp" GotFocus="AllMatching_GotFocus" MouseDoubleClick="AllMatching_MouseDoubleClick" ForceCursor="True">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                            </Trigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="LightGray"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGray"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="White" />
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
            <Button Content="Test" x:Name="cmdtest" Click="cmdtest_Click"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.Xaml.cs

```
namespace TypeSelect
 {

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    VM_Data ViewModel;
    DM_Data Existing;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new VM_Data();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        AllMatching.ItemsSource = ViewModel.DynamicData;
        ViewModel.CurrentRec = Existing= ViewModel.AllData[new Random().Next(0, ViewModel.AllData.Count - 1)];
        TxtMail.Text = (ViewModel.CurrentRec != null) ? ViewModel.CurrentRec.Name : "";

    }

    private void cmdtest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void TxtMail_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
        {
            ViewModel.CurrentRec = (DM_Data)AllMatching.SelectedItem;
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = (ViewModel.CurrentRec != null) ? ViewModel.CurrentRec.Name : "";
            //ViewModel.CurrentRec.SearchText = ViewModel.CurrentRec.Name;
            ViewModel.ListVisibility = ViewModel.ListVisibility.Equals(Visibility.Collapsed) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (ViewModel.ListVisibility.Equals(Visibility.Visible))
            {
                AllMatching.ScrollIntoView(ViewModel.CurrentRec);
            }
            else
            {
                Existing = ViewModel.CurrentRec;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Escape))
        {
            ViewModel.CurrentRec = Existing;
            ViewModel.ListVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = (ViewModel.CurrentRec != null) ? ViewModel.CurrentRec.Name : "";
        }
        else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Up))
        {
            AllMatching.SelectedIndex = AllMatching.SelectedIndex > 0 ? AllMatching.SelectedIndex - 1 : AllMatching.SelectedIndex;
            ViewModel.CurrentRec = (DM_Data)AllMatching.SelectedItem;
            AllMatching.ScrollIntoView(ViewModel.CurrentRec);
        }
        else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Down))
        {
            AllMatching.SelectedIndex = AllMatching.SelectedIndex < AllMatching.Items.Count ? AllMatching.SelectedIndex + 1 : AllMatching.SelectedIndex;
            ViewModel.CurrentRec = (DM_Data)AllMatching.SelectedItem;
            AllMatching.ScrollIntoView(ViewModel.CurrentRec);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewModel.DynamicData = ViewModel.AllData.Where(item => item.Name.StartsWith(TxtMail.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList<DM_Data>();
            AllMatching.ItemsSource = ViewModel.DynamicData;
            ViewModel.CurrentRec = (AllMatching.Items.Count > 0) ? ViewModel.DynamicData.Where(item => item.Name.StartsWith(TxtMail.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault() : null;
            if (AllMatching.Visibility.Equals(Visibility.Collapsed))
            {
                AllMatching.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                AllMatching.ScrollIntoView(ViewModel.CurrentRec);
            }
        }
    }

    private void TxtMail_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DM_Data Existing = ViewModel.CurrentRec;
        ViewModel.ListVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }

    private void TxtMail_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.ListVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }

    private void TxtMail_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        ViewModel.ListVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        AllMatching.ScrollIntoView(ViewModel.CurrentRec);

    }

    private void AllMatching_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.CurrentRec = (DM_Data)AllMatching.SelectedItem;
        ViewModel.ListVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        AllMatching.ScrollIntoView(ViewModel.CurrentRec);

    }

    private void AllMatching_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.ListVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void AllMatching_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
        {
            TxtMail.Text = ViewModel.CurrentRec.Name;
            ViewModel.ListVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    private void AllMatching_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.CurrentRec = (DM_Data)AllMatching.SelectedItem;
        TxtMail.Text = (ViewModel.CurrentRec != null) ? ViewModel.CurrentRec.Name : "";
        //ViewModel.CurrentRec.SearchText = ViewModel.CurrentRec.Name;
        ViewModel.ListVisibility = ViewModel.ListVisibility.Equals(Visibility.Collapsed) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (ViewModel.ListVisibility.Equals(Visibility.Visible))
        {
            AllMatching.ScrollIntoView(ViewModel.CurrentRec);
        }
        else
        {
            Existing = ViewModel.CurrentRec;
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set the Text property of TxtMail via DataBinding?

Bind it to a source property of the view model:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtMail" Binding="{Binding Mail}"   />
```

`Mail` is a property of the `VM_Data` class, just like `Name`.

> The `ItemSource` of `ListBox` named `AllMatching` is being set from Code-Behind since it is changing programatically with text search patterns. How can i set it from XAML?

You should bind this one as well:

```
<ListBox x:Name="AllMatching" ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicData}" ...>
```

For this to work, `DynamicData` must be a *property*:

```
public List<DM_Data> DynamicData { get; set; }
```

If you are adding items dynamically to it, you should make it an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<DM_Data> DynamicData { get; set; }
```

> Is there a way i can remove the logic of GUI Control Events and include the same in XAML?

XAML is a *markup* language. It is not a programming language. But you should look into commands: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/.

Comment: :tx.I have implemented the first two.About commands,i willl read soon and post questions.plz keep replying to my questions..tx in advance :-).